# InnerText and innerHTML return only part of script tag contents in Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate front-end tests for client's webpage in Selenium (java). I need to retrieve data from the contents of <script></script> tag from the HTML below.

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
<script src="/smth/smth/script.js"></script>
<script src="/another/smth/script.js"></script>
<script>
    var A = 2;
    var B = "this-is-random-set-of-numbers-and-letters";
    var C = "Thats a name";
    var D = {"key" : "value", "key2" : "value2", "keyN" : "valueN"};
    var E = {"key" : "value", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : [{"keyA": "valueA", "keyB":"valueB", "keyC":"valueC"}, {"keyD": "valueD", "keyE":"valueE", "keyF":"valueF"}], "keyN" : "valueN"};
    var F = [];
    var _G = "another-random-set-of-numbers-and-letters";
    var _H = "_letters";
    var I = null;
    var J = true;
    var K = null;
    var L = "yet-another-random-set-of-numbers-and-letters";
    var M = "Status name";
    var N = {"key":[],"key1":["value1","value2","value3","value4""]};
    var O = null;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When trying to retrieve the contents, I only get the following values:

```
  var _G = "another-random-set-of-numbers-and-letters";
  var _H = "_letters";
  var N = {"key":[],"key1":["value1","value2","value3","value4""]};
```

I tried the following approaches:

```
By by = By.xpath("//script[not(@src)]")
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(60));
WebElement myElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));
String value = myElement.getAttribute("innerHTML"); // as well as innerText
```

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String query = "var listOfScriptElements = document.getElementsByTagName('script'); return listOfScriptElements[(listOfScriptElements.length)-1].innerText;"; // yes, the <script> in question will always be at the end of the list
String jsResponse = js.executeScript(query).toString();
```

All options return the same response - only 3 variables instead of the whole content.
I thought maybe it was loading dynamically, so I paused script execution manually (before trying to find the element), confirmed in browser's developer console that the contents were already available in DOM, then unpaused the script - it did not help.
Is it possible there's some sort of bot management blocking me from accessing only part of <script> tag? It's the only part of the webpage I am unable to reach.

Comment: Additional info: running System.out.println(driver.getPageSource()) also returns that <script>...</script> tag with only 3 values instead of full content available in browser's dev console.

Answer (score 0):

This xpath `"//script[not(@src)]"` seems to be problematic.

Using different locator and  `element.getAttribute("innerHTML")` works fine.

```
List<WebElement> scriptTags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("script"));
for (WebElement scriptTag: scriptTags) {
    String src = scriptTag.getAttribute("src"); // getting empty string for the third script tag (not null)
    if (src.length() == 0) {
        String innerHTML = scriptTag.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        System.out.println(innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Using different locator returns the same result - I ran your example just to make sure. Also, I think that if the locator was an issue, we'd receive an empty string or an exception, not part of content we want to get (this is honestly what bugs me the most - how is it I get part of it instead of nothing or everything?).

Comment: Good point. Check browser and driver versions, update if not in last stable version. Another cause may be in the web itself, put some sleep before getting the innerHTML, just to verify all the vars all there.

Comment: Browser & driver are in latest stable version (108.0.5359.71), tried running the script with sleeps and with manual pauses in execution before even posting the question, still nothing. That's why I'm suspecting some sort of bot blocker, but I don't know much about them :/

Comment: Bot blocker would just slow down or deny access. But asking your webmaster still worth. Compare result with same test on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script (just add `driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");`) to let the webmaster see the difference.